# How do I loop nextInt to define variables in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

the question I've asked isn't too clear but essentially I have been tasked to:

> Write a program to read in 5 integer numbers from the user.  You
> should store the numbers in an array.
>
> Use loops for efficiency.

I would know how to do this if it weren't for loops, however I am unsure how to use loops for this certain task.

What I have is this (I know this is completely wrong I was just trying to base it on the example from the book).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fivenumbersloops {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Scanner aids = new Scanner(System.in);  
    int[] numbers = new int[5];             
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a whole number: ");
        numbers[0] = aids.nextInt();
        numbers[0]++;
    
    }while (numbers[0]==numbers[5]);
    

    }

}
```

I know it's the bottom bit which is completely wrong, but if someone could help point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Nice that your Scanner has aids, do you require Array or is it allowed to use ArrayList ?

Comment: @Stefan "store the numbers in an array".

Comment: When you have a fixed number of times to do something, use a for loop. Please try to adhere to Java naming conventions: class name starts with uppercase: `FiveNumbersLoops `.

Comment: You learned C first, correct? This very much looks like pointer arithmetic to me.

Comment: It doesn't say so lets assume whichever makes it easier aha

Comment: `int[] numbers = IntStream.generate(new Scanner(System.in)::nextInt).limit(5).toArray();`

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It is clear and legit.

Comment: @m0skit0 ohh didn't realise class names had to as well, will start doing it from now on thankyou

Comment: @Lothar i did not, i started javascript a few days ago so I still suck

Comment: It is not mandatory, just a convention, but it is usually good to start using conventions as soon as possible.

Comment: @m0skit0 also idm getting downvoted, im honestly so shocked I got so many helpful answers so quickly, was expecting 1 over a few hours

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a for loop. This for loop initializes the variable i to 0, continues while i is less than 5 and increments i for each iteration. The variable i is used to specify the position to place the input number into the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner aids = new Scanner(System.in);  
    int[] numbers = new int[5];             
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a whole number: ");
        numbers[i] = aids.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot dude, i'll paste this in and give it a go

Comment: @MikeFoski Try to understand it first :)

Comment: @m0skit0  I think I am being dense here, but where did the 'int i' come from? Isn't it already defined as 'numbers'?

Comment: `i` is the counter, goes from 0 to 4, and it is used as the index on the array (0 being the first element). So in the first iteration, you're storing the number in `numbers[0]`, in the second iteration in `numbers[1]` and so on until `i` is equal to 5.

Comment: numbers is the array. i controls the position into the array.